# How should I uninstall PostgreSQL when the PostgreSQL program is not displayed in the program panel?

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation, uninstallation, odoo-16

I am learning Odoo and therefore need to install PostgreSQL. However, when I reached the final step of officially installing PostgreSQL, my computer suddenly shut down. After restarting, I found that there was no PostgreSQL program on my computer, but my installation directory and data directory are no longer empty folders. Now I want to uninstall PostgreSQL and reinstall it. If I follow the official tutorial of EDB, I need to find the PostgreSQL program in my program panel and uninstall it, but as I mentioned earlier, the PostgreSQL program is not displayed in my program panel, which makes things a bit tricky. What should I do now? How can I completely uninstall PostgreSQL?

[Here is my installation directory:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN9Lz.png)
[Here is my data directory:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6weJu.png)

Comment: You could use Yenthe's script which install all required program at the same time: https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript